# iis6 which app pool does each w3wp belong to?

Tags: iis-6, process, iis, worker-process

I have a run away worker process.
Which of the 10ish sites on this box is it thats going nuts?
How can I determine from the pid of the worker process which site he is?

Answer (score 1):

run

```
>c:\windows\system32\cscript iisapp.vbs
```

it outputs the pids and the names of the app pools associated.